# Compute the infinite series of the $\displaystyle{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n}.}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, infinite-product

Can somebody help me with this.

Compute the infinite series of the $\displaystyle{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n}.}$

I have no idea how to start with this.  This is my first time encounter with the problem.  I'm sorry.  If you could, I will appreciate this.

What I did by the way is to expand the product.  However, is there a way to do this in a way that it does not like doing the expanding classical form?

Comment: Try finding the product up to $n = 2, 3, 4$ and so on, writing out each term in the product. Do you notice a pattern?

Comment: You can't do the problem and you don't want some specific type of solutions ? Maybe at least solve it the simple obvious way and show why you don't like it before asking for restrictions won the solution

Answer (score 4):

Your product is $\prod_n\frac{(n+1)/(n+2)}{n/(n+1)}$, which telescopes to $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this acceptable or can somebody point out my mistake?

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2+2k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{2{(2)}}{1{(3)}} \cdot \frac{{(3)}(3)}{{(2)}(4)} \cdots \frac{(n-1){(n-1)}}{(n-2){n}} \cdot \frac{{(n)}{(n)}}{{(n-1)}{(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{n(n+2)} \right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2(n+1)}{n+2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\left(1 + 1/n\right)}{1 + 2/n} = 2$.